# CMAKE 3.3.2: Set build type in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile

Is there a way to set the build type from CMakeLists.txt? So that with (or without) generating a new makefile when I compile it should go with the release mode. I try something along the lines of:

```
set(DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")
```

But it doesn't work (compiles in debug mode). This is on a linux system. Thanks.

Comment: `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is a command line option that you would use when running cmake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's simply:

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")
```