# How to get different build type for c++ via cmake at once?

Tags: c++, cmake, clang++, address-sanitizer

I have a cpp project and using external(git submodule) directory for sanitizer. Here is how my project looks like.

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── Dockerfile
├── externals
│   └── sanitizers-cmake
├── jenkins
│   └── submodule
├── Jenkinsfile
├── README.md
├── scripts
│   └── run.sh
└── src
    └── main.cpp
```

Sanitizer came from externals directory. Here is my cmake file

```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(testproject)


set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fPIC -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fPIC -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic")

add_executable(intro src/main.cpp)

ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(debug
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}  
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target all
  COMMENT "Switch CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to Debug"
  )

ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(release
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target all
  COMMENT "Switch CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to Release"
  )


ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(asanitizer
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=ASAN ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target all
  COMMENT "Switch CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to Address Sanitizer"
  )

include("cmake/cppcheck.cmake")
include("cmake/clang-dev-tools.cmake")

include("cmake/sanitizer.cmake")
```

I edited my CMakeLists.txt and I defined 3 build types debug, release and address sanitizer. Currently, after invoking CMake, I can run the make with one of the following params. My aim is to build them parallel and get all 3 binaries at the same time. Currently, I am overriding them. And I cannot avoid calling make. It should be simply handled by Cmake

```
$ make debug | release | asanitizer


Host= Debian 10
Compiler= clang-7
cmake= 3.13 
generator= ninja
```

Comment: What sanitizer are you using? Does the CMake complete successfully? Does your executable build? You update the CMake Module path, but do not use it afterward (e.g. via a call to `find_package()`). Do you intend to have CMake find the sanitizer external package in this manner?

Comment: Actually cmake is completing  and building successfully. I added find_package(), but still cannot see sanitizers.

Comment: What sanitizer are you using?

Comment: when invoke for address sanitizer like `cmake  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=ASAN ..` it's work. but how to set build type in CMakeLists.txt

Comment: "but how to set build type in CMakeLists.txt" - I have asked google and it has answered with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558795/cmake-3-3-2-set-build-type-in-cmakelists-txt.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Let me make more clear by editing the Qs

Comment: "My aim is to build them parallel and get all 3 binary at the same time. Currently, I am overriding them." - Unless your build tool (generator) is a multi-configuration one, you need to create **different build trees** for different configurations. In other words, you need to use **different binary directories** for different configurations. In command line you may specify build directory with `-B` option. Alternatively, for `add_custom_target` you may specify `WORKING_DIRECTORY`, so all `cmake` commands will be run from that directory.